# Enviar datos form a backend (PHP) para guardar en bd mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, html5, webforms

Estoy intentando que al enviar un formulario me envie los datos al backend para así poder crear una nueva estancia en la base de datos.

El caso es que no me da ningún error, y me muestra el alert de que se ha hecho correctamente, pero no se crea en la base da datos, no se si es que no estoy tratando los datos bien en el controlador o como, la query funciona correctamente porque he probado a añadir la estancia de forma hardcoedada y funciona.

El formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form id="formCountry">
                <div class="modal fade" id="addPaisModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Afegeix País</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="agreementCode">Nom</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="nomPais" class="form-control" id="nomPais" placeholder="Nom país">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="agreementStudies">Programa</label>
                                        <select name="programaPais" class="form-control" id="programaPais">
                                            <?php foreach ($programs as $program): ?>
                                                <option>
                                                    <?php echo $program->codiPrograma;?>
                                                </option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Tanca</button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="addCountry" class="btn btn-primary">Guarda</button>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Al darle al botón submit mediante jquery lo envío por post al backend (los 2 alerts me muestran los valores correctamente):

```
$(document).on("submit", "#formCountry", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData;
    data.append("programaPais", $("#programaPais").val());
    data.append("nomPais", $("#nomPais").val());
    alert($("#programaPais").val());
    alert( $("#nomPais").val());


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admin.php/updateTableCountries",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(t,e,c){
            alert("Pais creat correctament!");
            $("#addPaisModal").modal('hide');

        },
        error: function(e, a, t) {alert("Error al crear el pais!");}
    });
})
```

Controlador (sigo arquitectura MVC):

```
 case 'updateTableCountries':
            $data= $_POST['data'];
            array_push($parameters, $data);
            $actionName = $controller;
            break;
```

Función:

```
public function updateTableCountries($parameters){
    require 'models/CountriesModel.php';
    $countriesModel = new CountriesModel();

    $data = $parameters[0];

    $countriesModel->addCountry($data['programaPais'],$data['nomPais']);

    $countriesModel->disconnect();
}
```

Query:

```
public function addCountry($codiPrograma,$nomPais){
    try {
        $consulta = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO pais(codiPrograma,nomPais) VALUES (?,?)");
        $consulta->execute(array($codiPrograma,$nomPais));

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $obj = $e;
    }

}
```

Alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Comment: hace un var_dump o un print_r de la consulta a ver si te están llegando bien los valores, y todo lo que te traiga como valor pegalo en el phpmyadmin

Comment: Gracias, ya he podido solucionarlo! @CSHKtimporta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido solucionarlo. He añadido los siguientes cambios:

Controlador:

```
 case 'updateTableCountries':
            $data['programaPais'] = $_POST['programaPais'];
            $data['nomPais'] = $_POST['nomPais'];
            array_push($parameters, $data);
            $actionName = $controller;
            break;
```

Función:

```
 public function updateTableCountries($parameters){
    require 'models/CountriesModel.php';
    $countriesModel = new CountriesModel();

    $data = $parameters[0];
    $codi = $data['programaPais'];
    $nom = $data['nomPais'];

    $countriesModel->addCountry($codi,$nom);

    $countriesModel->disconnect();
}
```